# ng-tags-input not able to choose an option from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I've got some issue in this directive; the first one is that i can't see any item in the list.. Then sometimes it says that ngRepeat has duplicate values and then even if i'm able to see something i can't select it and put it on the input! How is possible? Here's a plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/vTwOqcN4pm3FgKLYlLu9?p=preview

By the way, this is the html code part:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags"add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
      <auto-complete min-length="1"
                    source="loadTags($query)"
                    template="my-custom-template"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>

     <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-custom-template">
        <div class="right-panel>
            <span ng-bind-html="$highlight($getDisplayText())"></span>
            <h1 style="font-size: 15px!important" class="uk-margin-remove">
                {{data.name}}
            </h1>
        </div>
    </script>

  </body>
```

And here the angular:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tags = [];


  $scope.loadTags = function(query) {

            return $http.get('tags.json', {
                cache: true
            }).then(function(data) {
                $scope.names = data.data.data;

                return $scope.names;
            });
        };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on your problem and find a solution in a simple way. I have tested it and it works. I hope that is what you are looking for.

Angular script file

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tags = [];
  $scope.names = [];


  $scope.loadTags = function() {

            return $http.get('tags.json').then(function(response) {
              var data = response.data.data.data;
              $scope.names = [];

              for (var tag in data)
              {
                $scope.names.push(data[tag].name);
              }

                return $scope.names;
            });
        };

});
```

HTML file

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
<auto-complete min-length="1"
        source="loadTags()"
        template="my-custom-template"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
<p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Man, tomorrow I'll check your solution.I hope it works. By the way i will let you know tomorrow.thanks!

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily complicated since it forces you to write code that transforms the original data. The tags input control is flexible enough to allow you to override the property names so that you don't have to write this extra logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. The only issue I see is that in you tags.json, you data.data objects should be in the form of {id: idVal, text: nameVal}. That is, the display field name should be 'text' instead of 'name'.

Comment: So this directive works only with a "text" field in the json?

Comment: You can override that by setting the display-property property to display-property="name" on the tag input directive.

Comment: And while you are at it, you should probably also set the key-property="id" since that also defaults to text. The keyProperty is what the control uses to distinctly identify the different items.

Comment: Mmh i will try tomorrow.can you please stay tuned so tomorrow i will write here the response?

Comment: I may not be able to since tomorrow is a Holiday. However, you can test it quickly by simply adding the following to the end of you tag-input directive in the plunker:  display-property="name" key-property="id"

Comment: I just forked your plunker and made the change. You can test it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5LrxIGnYBP25CPO4KFo6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

use this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/QFjUPSUENc8RiqipRT28?p=preview

use `key-property = "id" and display-property="name` for removing duplicacy error ,and for showing list